# How to branch and using a standalone server efficiently (e.g. Apache)

Tags: apache, branch, dns, httpd.conf, git-branch

I can see branching is easy if you're using rails or django, which has development servers in their development directories (django-admin.py runserver).

At the moment I'm developing php served by Apache (windows). If I make a branch out of my php directory, I need to edit httpd.conf and add the new branch.

Is there a way I can get a branch just to work instantly with apache? I'd love it to be like this: `http://master.project.localhost -> /projects/master`, `http://testing.project.localhost -> /projects/testing`

I've read that the hostfiles can't have wildcards. Must I use a DNS-software or something to get this streamlined?

Also, my projects can't run i directories, http://project.localhost/master and http://project.localhost/testing, is not working

Comment: I don't see in your question the reason for the 'git-branching' tag. Do you want to automate something based on git branches?

Comment: If that is a way to accomplish my problem, yes. But the problem isn't git-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Look at sites-available/sites-enabled in Apache so that you can run multiple sites with one server (using a2ensite, etc).